Psutil memory_info return weird values
I want to measure the memory usage of a process and I am using something like this:
# inner psutil function
def process_memory():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    mem_info = process.memory_info()
    return mem_info.rss

# decorator function
def profile(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        mem_before = process_memory()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        mem_after = process_memory()
        logging.info("{}:consumed memory (before, after, diff): {:,}".format(
            func.__name__,
            mem_before, mem_after, mem_after - mem_before))

        return result
    return wrapper

@profile
def run_job():
    many_calculations...

run_job()

It works fine but I noticed that the last term in the print of consumed memory, the one is supposed to be mem_after - mem_before gives me weird values, like:
mem_before, mem_after, diff
318,566,400
318,574,592
318,578,688
318,566,400

which is clearly not the subtraction of the first two numbers. Any idea what is actually printing?
cheers,
